# Injecting 2D int array in a spring bean

Tags: java, spring, multidimensional-array

I have seen [how to inject an int array in spring bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8937743/how-to-inject-an-int-array-in-spring-bean). I was wondering if we can try injecting a 2d-array. I tried following code:

```
...
<bean id="myBean" class="com.rohit.spring.MyClass">
    <property name="myIntArray" value="{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}" />
</bean>
...
```

The class looks like:

```
Class MyCLass
{
    private Integer[][] myIntArray;

    public Integer[][] getMyIntArray(){
        return this.myIntArray;
    }
    public void setMyIntArray(Integer[][] myIntArray){
        this.myIntArray = myIntArray;
    }
}
```

The error thrown reads:

> "Invalid property 'myIntArray' of bean class
>   [com.rohit.spring.MyClass]: Bean
>   property 'myIntArray' is not writable or has an invalid
>   setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return
>   type of the getter?"

Any idea if it's not possible or if I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: You could create each 1 dimensional array as individual beans in the way that the other page tells you to, and then create another bean which is an array of those beans.

Comment: Hi @Ben Green, yup that's one of the work arounds, but still, the question is - is it out of scope to inject a 2D array or I am not following the correct syntax. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
<beans:bean id="someClass" class="com.you.SomeClass" >
   <beans:property name="myIntArray">
       <beans:list>
           <beans:list>
               <beans:value>1</beans:value>
               <beans:value>2</beans:value>
               <beans:value>3</beans:value>
           </beans:list>
           <beans:list>
               <beans:value>4</beans:value>
               <beans:value>5</beans:value>
               <beans:value>6</beans:value>
           </beans:list>
           <beans:list>
               <beans:value>7</beans:value>
               <beans:value>8</beans:value>
               <beans:value>9</beans:value>
           </beans:list>
       </beans:list>
   </beans:property>
</beans:bean>
```

Or:

```
<beans:bean id="someClass" class="com.you.SomeClass" >
   <beans:property name="myIntArray">
       <beans:array> 
           <beans:array>
               <beans:value>1</beans:value>
               <beans:value>2</beans:value>
               <beans:value>3</beans:value>
           </beans:array>
           <beans:array>
               <beans:value>4</beans:value>
               <beans:value>5</beans:value>
               <beans:value>6</beans:value>
           </beans:array>
           <beans:array>
               <beans:value>7</beans:value>
               <beans:value>8</beans:value>
               <beans:value>9</beans:value>
           </beans:array> 
       </beans:array>
   </beans:property>
</beans:bean>
```

**UPDATE: Supply your own converter**

Another way would be to use [Converter](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/convert/converter/Converter.html)s. Here is an example implementation:

```
public class IntArrayConverter implements Converter<String, int[][]> {
    @Override
    public int[][] convert(String source) {
        if(isBlank(source)) {
            return new int[0][0];
        }

        String[] subArraysStrs = source.split(":");
        int[][] result = new int[subArraysStrs.length][];

        for(int i = 0; i < subArraysStrs.length; i++) {
            String subArrayStr = trim(subArraysStrs[i]);
            if(isBlank(subArrayStr)) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException();
            }

            String[] subArrayElementStrs = subArrayStr.split(",");
            int[] subArray = new int[subArrayElementStrs.length];
            for(int j = 0; j < subArray.length; j++) {
                String elementStr = trim(subArrayElementStrs[j]);
                subArray[j] = Integer.parseInt(elementStr);
            }
            result[i] = subArray;
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Now, tell spring that it can use this converter by declaring the following in your configuration:

```
<bean id="conversionService"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ConversionServiceFactoryBean">
        <property name="converters">
            <list>
                <bean class="com.example.IntArrayConverter" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

and then:

```
<bean class="com.you.SomeClass">
    <property name="myIntArray" value="1,2,3:4,5,6:7,8,9"></property>
</bean>
```

My [Converter](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/convert/converter/Converter.html) is implemented to be used without the curly braces around each sub-array for simplicity. That is, instead of

```
<property name="myIntArray" value="{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}"></property>
```

I am going with

```
<property name="myIntArray" value="1,2,3:4,5,6:7,8,9"></property>
```

If you want, you can modify the code to interpret any kind of string format.
For more details about [Converter](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/convert/converter/Converter.html)s, you can look [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#core-convert).

**Note**: The registered `ConversionService` will be availabel to your entire app. That is, it will be used whenever there is a need to convert a `String` into an `int[][]`. Also, even though you provide only one converter, all the default converters are registered anyway, so you won't lose their benefits.

Comment: @Bashit Parikh: +1 for the answer. I have given a simpler version of my real problem where I have around 100 entries in every array, could there be another way than writing hundreds of `<beans:value>...</beans:value>`? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

### Yet another way

To complement the answer of Bhashit Parikh, yet another simple way of injecting an `int[][]` array via an XML configuration file is as follows:

```
<beans:bean id="someClass" class="com.you.SomeClass" >
    <beans:property name="myIntArray">
        <beans:list>
           <beans:value>1,2,3</beans:value>
           <beans:value>4,5,6</beans:value>
           <beans:value>7,8,9</beans:value>
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>
```